# If $CD=AC=CB$ and $\angle B=x^\circ$, then find $\angle BAD$.

Tags: geometry

> If $CD=AC=CB$, and the measure of $\angle B$ is $x^\circ$, then the measure of $\angle BAD$ is ...
>
> A) $2x^\circ$ 
> B) $180-x^\circ$ 
> C) $90^\circ$ 
> D) $3x^\circ$

[image]

Comment: Not super-well drawn picture, as $AC$ should be (at least approximately) equal to $BC$ ...

Comment: Sorry,check the picture now, it is well drawn

Comment: That's better. The thing that first comes to my mind is that this could be a triangle drawn inside a circle (centre is at $C$). What can you conclude?

Comment: That AC,BC,CD each of them is radius of circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $BC=AC$, then $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles; similarly, since $AC=CD$, then $\triangle ACD$ is also isosceles.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and $\angle ABC=x^\circ$, then $\angle CAB=x^\circ$. Since the sum of the interior angles of any triangle is $180^\circ$, then $\angle ACB=180-2x$. Then $\angle ACD=2x$ and 
$\angle CAD=\angle CDA=90-x$. Hence, $\angle BAD=x+90-x=90$.

Comment: @AbdallahHamad Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Nice and easy to follow. However I think the last conclusion $\angle CAD = \angle CDA = 90-x$ could use some explanation (ie $\angle CAD + \angle CDA = 180 - \angle ACD$) to make the reasoning a bit clearer on the same level as the rest.

Comment: @skyking Thanks for the comment. I was in a rush and could not write the answer in a step by step format since I thought it is clear. I will edit it as you suggested. In the meanwhile, if you want, please feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$90^0$ as C is circumcentre of triangle ABD. With BD as one of its diameter.